A data pipeline in Airflow throws [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1131)
I have a VM in the Google Cloud Platform that is hosting an Apache Airflow instance. I have created 10 data pipelines in Airflow that extract data through API calls, store the results in a Cloud Storage bucket, and then is copied into BigQuery tables. These pipelines have been running smoothly till now. However, for 3 days, the pipeline fails with the message "[SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1131)" on the 3rd step (GCS to BQ). I am not able to understand the reason. Please help. Below is the code that I used.

Sharing the error message below:
[2024-04-01 11:52:57,344] {http.py:163} WARNING - Sleeping 0.23 seconds before retry 1 of 1 for request: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest, after [SSL] internal error (_ssl.c:1131)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
